# Work done pulling a leaky bucket

Tags: calculus

> A bucket that weighs $4.6$ pounds and a rope of negligible weight are used to draw water from a well that is $80$ feet deep. The bucket is filled with $35$ pounds of water and is pulled up at a rate of $2.7$ feet per second, but water leaks out of a hole in the bucket at a rate of $0.3$ pounds per second. Find the work done pulling the bucket to the top of the well.

So far I got $ \ \int_0^{80} \ x[39.6-(.11x^2)] \ dx \ \ $  but my webwork keeps telling me it's wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't the "pounds per foot" term only be $ \ 0.11 x \ $ ?

Comment: The weight is lifted a distance $dx$.

Comment: You have two problems.  One is the square on $x$ as explained by André Nicolas.  Another  (I don't know if your webwork cares about this precision) is that $\frac {0.3}{2.7} \neq 0.11$

Comment: No it usually lets me stop at 2 decimal points.Am I just integrating incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you are working with height. It doesn't matter much, but let $x=0$ be the bottom of the well. Let us calculate the work done in lifting the bucket from height $x$ to height "$x+dx$." The weight of the bucket when we are at height $x$ is $39.6 -\frac{0.3}{2.7}x$. So the work done in moving from $x$ to $x+dx$ is approximately $\left(39.6 -\frac{0.3}{2.7}x\right)\,dx$ foot pounds. "Add up," (integrate) from $x=0$ to $x=80$. We get that work done is
$$\int_0^{80} \left(39.6 -\frac{0.3}{2.7}x\right)\,dx.$$

**Added:** Integrate. An antiderivative is $39.6x-\frac{0.3}{2(2.7)}x^2$. Now calculate.

Comment: But when I solve for it I get -387.556 and a negative number would not work.

Comment: I had $0.27$ and the speed is $2.7$. Decimal point moved. You will find it is right.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I'm not sure why I thought to add the extra x's in my original answer